# How do i point make to use a particular system library in a build?

Tags: firefox, build, makefile, mozilla, gnu-make

I've tried putting this in the local Makefile :

```
INCLUDE +=  -I/opt/local/include
```

and tried putting this in the mozconfig:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include" export CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include"
```

But i still get :

```
error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
```

How do i get make to find the right libraries?

Comment: What happens when you try to compile by hand, without Make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to source//config/myconfig.mk

`CFLAGS += -I/path/to/includes -L/path/to/libs -l

CXXFLAGS += -I/path/to/includes -L/path/to/libs -l`